# how to stop onclick event

Tags: jquery, onclick

```
<p class="clickMe" id="one">click</p>
<p class"clickMe"  >click2</p>


<script>
$('.clickMe').on('click', function(e) {
alert("click");
$('#one').removeClass('.clickMe');

    });

</script>
```

Why does it still alert me when I remove the class 'clickMe'. I don't know why it's registering the click event more then once. How can I prevent the p tag from clicking more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because event handlers are attached to the object (not to class), once you remove class from object you don't remove event handler.

You need to execute:

```
$('#one').off('click');
//or
$('#one').unbind('click');
```

Off (Unbind) will remove event handler.

http://api.jquery.com/off/

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your script to this:

```
$(this).on('click', '.clickMe', function(e) {
   alert("click");
   $('#one').removeClass('clickMe');
});
```

The way you have it any element that has the class `clickMe` gets bound at start up and it stays that way.

The way I have it the event gets bound to the document and only triggered when the clicked element is `clickMe`. Thus the latter is more dynamic.

Comment: Is there a good way to select a dynamic element after start up? One that the inner text has been changed?

Comment: @james I might now fully get what you want to accomplish, but you can do the above at any time. It is just extreemly suited for the start-up.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed that by doing it this way $(this).on('click', '.clickMe', function(e) { actually wont register on a touchscreen device but doing it like this $('.clickMe').on('click', function(e) { does work.. Not sure why but as long as one way works I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .on() use .one() - that should do it. http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
    alert( "Displayed only once." );
});
```